# Select statement take more time in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Statement 1 : select top 1000 pmch.Columnname1

Statement 2 : select top 1000 pmch.*

Statement 2 executes quicker the  Statement 1.

I know that using "SELECT * " will affect performance so should use column names instead of " * ".

But, here it works differently.

Can anyone suggest under which condition these type of issue occurs?

Comment: top 1000 without an order by will give you 1000 random rows. What is the difference in execution time? My guess is that it is a coincidence

Comment: Are the actual execution plans the same?

Comment: Did you literally run `SELECT TOP 1000 columnname` and then `SELECT TOP 1000 *` and compare the times? Try running them _multiple times_. It's _possible_ the data was not in memory, so the first query paid to put it all there, then the second query was faster because the data was already in memory. Though you give no indication of what "more time" means - milliseconds more, seconds more, minutes more? Did you compare execution plans? Are they using the same operators against the same indexes?

Comment: @Lennart just to be pedantic, `random` is a very specific thing, I think the point is rather that leaving out `ORDER BY` means you can not be sure you will get the same 1,000 rows every time. SQL Server will give you the first 1,000 rows in whatever way it deems most efficient / convenient, and that may remain stable over time, but it could also change.

Comment: random in the sense that it is not deterministic (from the end-users view).

Comment: @Lennart Understood, but again, being pedantic, "random" and "not deterministic" are different conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

A large difference in time makes me think there is significantly different IO happening for these two queries.

The second query qualifies for [trivial](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/04/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.html) optimization. Likely it is performing a table scan, on the heap or a clustered index.

The first query projects only a single column. If there is an index with that column as a leading key the optimizer is likely to choose to read from that index as doing so will require fewer IOs.

So how do fewer IOs result in longer elapsed times? Let's suppose the base table's pages are sequentially ordered on-disk and can be efficiently scanned, perhaps with pre-fetching. This can be fast. Further, let's suppose the index is badly fragmented on-disk so each new page read requires an on-disk seek. This will be slow.

In summary, statement 1 uses an index scan on a badly fragmented index suffering slow seek times while statement 2 uses efficient sequential disk scan.

To be sure look at the two query plans. If I'm correct the respective objects read will be obvious in each plan. The amount of fragmentation can be found from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#detecting-the-amount-of-fragmentation). That link also gives the solution. Note that fragmentation [need not be a problem](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/), depending on the hardware and workload.

Fragmentation can occur due to rows being added in the middle of the key range. This is a natural part of application usage. It can be mitigated by an appropriate [fill factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15). It can also happen when database files are shrunk. Don't do that.